# Firestore query to firebase query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I need the equivalent firebase realtime database query from the firestore query below

```
await db.collection('Events')
        .where('EventName', '>=', 'startcode')
        .where('EventName', '<', 'endcode').get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                const data = doc.data()
                searchList.push(data)



            })
        })
```

Comment: With Firebase real-time unfortunately you cannot stack queries. You’d have to use one of the queries https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query but the. You’d have to do the remaining filtering client side or server side depending on your app.

Comment: Hey @johnnoula, if my answer was helpful you can accept/upvote by clicking on the tick and up arrow icons else feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: @sychordCoder realtime database does allow [working with lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

Comment: @Dharmaraj understood I wanted to point out that you can’t stack the same query, poor wording.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [filtering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data):

```
const snapshot = await firebase
       .database()
       .ref("/ref/to/events")
       .orderBy("EventName")
       .startAt("start_code")
       .endBefore("end_code")
       .once("value")

console.log(snapshot.val())
```

> startAt() Return items greater than or equal to the specified key or
> value, depending on the order-by method chosen.

> endAt() Return items
> less than or equal to the specified key or value, depending on the
> order-by method chosen.

To use this query your db structure should look something like:

```
{
  events: {
    event1: {
      EventName: "event1name"
    },
    event2: {
      EventName: "event2name"
    }
  }
}
```